# Installing packages on offline ArchLinux system

Tags: archlinux

I want to install packages on a ArchLinux machine, which does not have internet connection.
I am following the link https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Offline_Installation_of_Packages (section "Normal Method: Pacman").

The command "pacman -Sp --noconfirm xorg-server" lists the dependency but not the complete
url to download from. Any ideas how to get the list of dependent packages with the url to download from. I am using pacman version 4.0.2-libalpm v7.0.2.

Comment: I just tried this with the same version of `pacman` and it works fine (I have internet connection). Maybe try specifying `--print-format %l`? It should be like that by default, though, so I don't believe it can change anything. Maybe something is wrong with the package database you are using?

Comment: using command "pacman -Sp --noconfirm --print-format %1 xorg-server" prints '%1' in multiple lines(21 times). Any pointers to check the validity of database.

Comment: It's `l` (lowercase L), not `1`, the digit.

Comment: All I can say is that I tried replacing my "extra" with the one downloaded from the wiki page (the i686 one), and it still works for me. With no luck here, I think you can flag your question to be migrated to unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @LevLevitsky substuting %1(one) with %l, prints only the package name with out the url info. The --print-format %l does not have any effect on the output.

Comment: That's both strange and expectable: `--print-format <format>
Specify a printf-like format to control the output of the --print operation. The possible attributes are: %n for pkgname, %v for pkgver, %l for location, %r for repo and %s for size.` I think it means that the package database contains package names instead of URLs. Did you use the `i686` or `x64` database? If the former, I'm completely out of ideas (except for moving the question to unix.SE).

Comment: Will it help if I get the list of dependencies on my system and paste it somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for offering help. But i am looking for a future proof solution.

Comment: You know what, I tried it again with no cheating this time (did all the steps). The "multilib" link seems broken, but I don't think it's relevant, multilib isn't enabled in my `pacman.conf` anyway. But `pacman -Sp xorg-server` fails saying `error: failed to prepare transaction (could not find database)`. Enabling debug output doesn't help much, either: `debug: returning error 15 from _alpm_sync_prepare : could not find database`.

Comment: You have uncommented some mirrors in `mirrorlist`, haven't you?

Comment: And your `pacman.conf` includes the `mirrorlist` for `[core]`, `[community]` and `[testing]`?

Comment: Not `testing`, I meant `extra`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reproduced the behavior you describe by disabling all repository mirrors.

```
$ pacman -Sp inkscape
gc-7.1-4-i686.pkg.tar.xz
gsl-1.15-2-i686.pkg.tar.xz
libsigc++-2.2.10-2-i686.pkg.tar.xz
glibmm-2.30.1-1-i686.pkg.tar.xz
cairomm-1.10.0-2-i686.pkg.tar.xz
pangomm-2.28.4-1-i686.pkg.tar.xz
atkmm-2.22.6-1-i686.pkg.tar.xz
gtkmm-2.24.2-2-i686.pkg.tar.xz
imagemagick-6.7.6.2-1-i686.pkg.tar.xz
inkscape-0.48.3.1-2-i686.pkg.tar.xz
```

When I fix it back, the output looks like:

```
$ pacman -Sp inkscape
ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/archlinux/extra/os/i686/gc-7.1-4-i686.pkg.tar.xz
ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/archlinux/extra/os/i686/gsl-1.15-2-i686.pkg.tar.xz
ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/archlinux/extra/os/i686/libsigc++-2.2.10-2-i686.pkg.tar.xz
ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/archlinux/extra/os/i686/glibmm-2.30.1-1-i686.pkg.tar.xz
ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/archlinux/extra/os/i686/cairomm-1.10.0-2-i686.pkg.tar.xz
ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/archlinux/extra/os/i686/pangomm-2.28.4-1-i686.pkg.tar.xz
ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/archlinux/extra/os/i686/atkmm-2.22.6-1-i686.pkg.tar.xz
ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/archlinux/extra/os/i686/gtkmm-2.24.2-2-i686.pkg.tar.xz
ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/archlinux/extra/os/i686/imagemagick-6.7.6.2-1-i686.pkg.tar.xz
ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/archlinux/extra/os/i686/inkscape-0.48.3.1-2-i686.pkg.tar.xz
```

Now to what probably needs to be fixed.

1) `/etc/pacman.conf`

Here's an excerpt from mine ("Repositories" section):

```
# Repository entries are of the format:
#       [repo-name]
#       Server = ServerName
#       Include = IncludePath
#
# The header [repo-name] is crucial - it must be present and
# uncommented to enable the repo.
#

[core]
#SigLevel = PackageRequired
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[extra]
#SigLevel = PackageOptional
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[community]
#SigLevel = PackageOptional
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
```

2) The mirror list (`/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist`)

The mirror list that you include in `pacman.conf` needs to have some records uncommented.

```
$ head /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
##
## Arch Linux repository mirrorlist
## Generated on 2011-08-16
##

## Any
Server = ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
Server = http://mirrors.kernel.org/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch

## Australia
```

and so on. Note that the URLs generated by `pacman -Sp` actually use the first entry in the mirror list.

3) Another note on the instructions in the [ArchWiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Offline_Installation_of_Packages): you don't actually need to download both `.db` and `.tar.gz` files. The `.db` files actually are tarballs themselves, and contain the very same files and folders. So you can just download `core.db`, `community.db` and `extra.db` and put them in `/var/lib/pacman/sync`.

Comment: Just curious. How did you figured out the problem?

Comment: I just wanted to know where the URL information was stored, then I saw that all the links were to one mirror and that mirror was the first in my mirror list. Besides, I was told that `.db` files contained the same as the rest of stuff there, and I checked that there were no URLs in there.